# Java project in Eclipse: The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting the following error after importing a project in Eclipse:

> The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

However, I have set the path as **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41** in Eclipse Kepler, through **Window » Preferences » Java » Installed JREs**.

Comment: i made "copy project" and error disappeared

Comment: The behaviour still occurs in Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2). The solution here can still resolve the problem.

Comment: I am facing this issue in Android studio, any solution for this ?

Comment: Reload the editor/project, and boom, it's fixed (solved when using vscode with springboot project).

Answer (score 287, accepted):

This is an annoying Eclipse Bug which seems to bite now and then. See http://dev-answers.blogspot.de/2009/06/eclipse-build-errors-javalangobject.html for a possible solution, otherwise try the following;

- Close the project and reopen it.
- Clean the project (It will rebuild the buildpath hence reconfiguring with the JDK libraries)

  OR
- Delete and Re-import the project and if necessary do the above steps again.

The better cure is to try NetBeans instead of Eclipse :-)

Comment: Same here. Bizarre Eclipse bug. The As the link says, removing the JRE library from project's classpath and re-add it fix the problem.

Comment: Oh for a world that didn't have contracts with IBM.

Comment: I had that error on an Android project, for me clicking on Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties fixed it.

Comment: @Zibbobz why do we need contract with IBM. I am still not able to resolve this with IBM Java.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to when you change the JAVA_HOME environment variable? I had changed my JAVA_HOME variable and this popped up. I just removed/readded the JRE library.

Comment: Intellij instead of net beans or Eclipse

Comment: We should be able to add a comment that all those people can vote for where NONE of the solutions worked. Otherwise the comments for this non-IDE are misleading.

Comment: Glad this bug still exists in Neon 3... *rolleyes*

Comment: @Alex well, since a solution as simple as close + reopen works, it's probably not that much of a pressing issue from the dev's view, especially if the source of the bug is tricky to find.

Comment: In my case the bug happens because the project was originally from another persons Eclipse... as the first comment mentions, rechoosing the JDK in ProjectProperties/Java Build Path fixes it.

Comment: It's 2021 and Eclipse still sucks.

Comment: It's 2022 and Eclipse still sucks.

Comment: I'm getting this in VS Code.

Comment: Might help others: Check out the first answer in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63446925/the-project-was-not-built-due-to-failed-to-init-ct-sym-for-c-program-files-jav

Comment: It's 2023 and Eclipse still sucks

Comment: Removing JRE did not work for me. Closing eclipse, reopening, cleaning the project and rebuilding worked for me.

Comment: It's 2023 and every IDE sucks. Stop discriminating.

Answer (score 278):

The following steps could help:

1. Right-click on project **» Properties » Java Build Path**
2. Select **Libraries** tab
3. Find the JRE System Library and remove it
4. Click **Add Library...** button at right side » Add the JRE System Library (Workspace default JRE)

Comment: In my case it occurred because i have accidentally removed the JRE while importing the project [my fault]. This gave me a clue to fix the issue.

Comment: in my case it wasn't exist at all, so I added it.

Comment: Although this worked in my case, solved 8 errors but gave me another 33!

Comment: I am facing this issue in Android studio, any solution for this ?

Answer (score 15):

This happened to me when I imported a Java 1.8 project from Eclipse Luna into Eclipse Kepler.

1. Right click on project > Build path > configure build path...
2. Select the Libraries tab, you should see the Java 1.8 jre with an error
3. Select the java 1.8 jre and click the Remove button
4. Add Library... > JRE System Library > Next > workspace default > Finish
5. Click OK to close the properties window
6. Go to the project menu > Clean... > OK

Et voilà, that worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

Here is how I solved it:
In Java-ADT: Windows - Preference - Java - Installed JREs
Just add another JRE, pointing to the 'jre' folder under your JDK folder. (jre is included in the jdk). Make sure you chose the new jre.

Answer (score 9):

Have you installed a different version JRE after , while using previous version of JRE in Eclipse .

if Not than :

1. Right click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
2. Go to 'Libraries' tab
3. Add Library -> JRE System Library -> Next -> Workspace default JRE (or you can Choose Alternate JRE form your System) -> Finish

if Yes than .

1. Right click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
2. Go to 'Libraries' tab
3. Remove Previous Version
4. Add Library -> JRE System Library -> Next -> Workspace default JRE (or you can Choose Alternate JRE from your System) -> Finish

Answer (score 8):

Object class is the base class for all the classes in java, if you are missing this it means you don't have the jdk libs in your buildpath. I don't know much about Kepler but you need to make sure it points to a correct jdk for compilation and a correct jre for running your java apps.

> However I have set the path as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41 from
>   eclipse Kepler toolbar->windows->preferences->java->installed jre

You are trying to point jdk instead of jre in your preferences. toolbar->windows->preferences->java->installed jre should point to a jre and not jdk.

Comment: I have tried with that as well. But still in the same error state.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be an Eclipse bug, though restarting Eclipse worked great for me, hope this helps somebody else too.

Edit: the next time I had this problem the solution above did not work - the problem was that the imported project I had - had the wrong java runtime set - which was not present (I had java 8 in my JRE present, but the project imported was set to Java 11, so I had to change the project java version to 8. Alternative would be to add more JRE's in the Eclipse preferences - if the project really needs a newer JRE to work)

Answer (score 7):

No amount of cleaning, closing/reopening the project&IDE, removing/adding the JRE in build path worked for me.

The solution I found was to remove the project from Eclipse (not from disk), remove the project's Eclipse files from the disk, and import into Eclipse again. That worked.

It is even faster if you are using Maven:

1. Close Eclipse (no need to remove the project)
2. Run `mvn clean eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`
3. Open Eclipse. Your project is still present and the problem should be gone.

Answer (score 5):

None of the other answers worked for me. But doing this did:

1. Right click the project in the package explorer.
2. Source > Clean up...
3. Next > Finish

When I did this Eclipse added an import into one of my classes. I think this occurred because I saved my project with a missing import, probably rushing to get home after work.

Comment: thanks ..its working..please explain me how it works ?

Comment: @SinghArjun I'm not sure but I think this happens when the project is saved with a missing import.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on project -->Show in Navigator 
In navigator view you can see .classpath file, do delete this file and build the project. This worked for me.
PS. If you have integrated you eclipse project with some version control like perfoce/svn , then unlinking the project before you delete the .classpath will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Another problem could be that the Android Project Build Target is not set.

1. Right-click the project
2. Choose Properties
3. Click Android
4. Tick the appropriate Project Build Target
5. Apply | OK

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue with play-java application on eclipse after adding a controller,
I removed and reinstalled JRE through build path and then removed and imported my project which solved this issue automatically.
 Thanks gyro.

Comment: This is the same as Ripon Al Wasim's answer, right?

Answer (score 2):

What solved my problem was to

1) Install the jdk under directory with no spaces:

```
C:/Java
```

Instead of

```
C:/Program Files/Java
```

This is a known issue in Windows. I fixed `JAVA_HOME` as well

2) I java 7 and java 8 on my laptop. So I defined the jvm using `eclipse.ini`. This is not a mandatory step if you don't have `-vm` entry in your `eclipse.ini`. I updated:

```
C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/bin/javaw.exe
```

Instead of:

```
C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/javaw.exe
```

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem. It was a maven project with the following snippet of pom.xml.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>9</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I had to change the following.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

If you have already installed JDK 11 and working with java 9 or java 10 as maven compiler, eclipse can not detect. Hence change the release to 11 or the actual installed version of JDK.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem in eclipse windows that I couldn't added dependant .class files from the JNI.
In order resolve the same, I ported all the code to NetBeans IDE.

[Can not add all the classes files from the JNI/JNA folder in Eclipse (JAVA, Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937206/can-not-add-all-the-classes-files-from-the-classes-folder-in-eclipse-java-wind)

Comment: Why is it down voted ? See I do tried all the possible solutions, still could not resolve the issue and then I ported code to NetBeans. I answered this because if anybody stuck up, in worst case, s(he) might get help.

Comment: You may be right but for me JNI/JNA worked fine (for eclipse - 4.9.0) after deleting existing library and setting up default jre library, close project, open project.

Answer (score 1):

While we are working with tomcat 6 and jdk 1.8 versions, some of the features will not work and this error you are getting is one. you need to change the jdk version to stable version(preferable jdk 1.6 or jdk 1.8_65) in eclipse to resolve this error.

in eclipse 
     step 1:   properties -> java build path -> jre system library(remove)
     step 2:   add -> jre system library  -> alternate jre -> installed jre                -> add -> Standard VM -> (in jre home, place jdk path) -> finish

now clean and check the project

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I have installed "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers", I uninstalled this and installed "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers". Problem solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me after unchecking 'User '--releae option' in eclipse Java-compiler

In eclipse step 1: properties -> java Complier -> uchecking 'User '--releae option' option -> finish

Java version 13.0.1
Eclipse version : Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Comment: This solved it for me but could anyone help me understand why?

Answer (score 1):

> However I have set the path as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41 from eclipse Kepler toolbar->windows->preferences->java->installed jre

If you have already added JRE and still showing error. try follow

right click on your project

project->build path-> configure build path -> java build path -> libraries tab -> select JRE system library and click edit button -> If alternative JRE is selected choose workspace default JRE.

this is how my error gone.

Answer (score 0):

Happend to me after I've installed some updates in eclipse but forgot to restart afterwards. So maybe restarting eclipse might help.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I'm not allowed to write comments yet.

Answer (score 0):

However trivial this might be, check your Java installation. For me, **rt.jar was missing**.

I found this after fiddling for half a day with Eclipse settings and getting nowhere.
Desperate, I finally decided to try compiling the project from the command line. I wasn't expecting to see anything wrong since I thought it's an Eclipse issue but to my astonishment I saw this:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

I don't know what happened to my Java installation and where did rt.jar go. Anyway this comes as a reminder to go through the fail checklist and tick all the boxes no matter how unbelievable they are. It would have saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project, select Maven -> Update project.
That should solve the issue.

Comment: doing eclipse -> maven -> update should be one of the step while troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a big modular project and the '**red X**' was showing only in the parent project.
I went to the parent project

> Properties -> Built Path

a removed the JRE Library there, just that, no JRE Library on the parent project anymore.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. In my case the problem was that I had some Java code producing `.java` files and I had accidentally created a file called `Class.java` (content doesn't seem to matter). Removing the file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this error happened after updating JAVA. if so go to eclipse.ini file in the same folder where eclipse existed. then change the line under -vm keyward to the new path of jre/bin folder to get the path go to programfiles -> java -> jre latest version -> bin folder copy the path and replace in line under -vm keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This error message occurs when a class/java-project is unable to resolve correct JDK libraries. Say, in my primary Project A, I was getting this error. This Project A had a maven dependency for a project B. Project B pointed to JDK-11. Project A pointed to JDK-9

Correction I did : Made Project also point to JDK-11. It resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle users, use eclipse plugin. I'm not using eclipse directly but `jdtls` on Neovim. This solves the issue for me.

#### build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
}
```

Then run

```
gradle cleanEclipse eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VScode
Try The following steps:

1. **click ctrl+shift+p** or **F1**
2. type: **Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace** >> Enter
3. at the buttom right coner click **Reload and delete**