# Eclipse message (The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

it's the first time I working with Eclipse but when I try to import any source I've this problem
1-The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
2-The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I tried some solutions like add library..>JRE System . but useless with me!!

Comment: 2-(Edit)- The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project

Comment: Do you have `JDK` not just `JRE` on your computer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind

Comment: I installed this file "jdk-8u40-windows-x64.exe" I have windows 8 64bit

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem for myself as well. If the typical uninstalling and reinstalling the JRE System Library in the Java Build Path didn't work for you, then I suggest you try to install the Java JDK from here:

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

Then, create a new workspace with default settings, and everything should be good. The reason why I had this problem is probably because I accidentally deleted something that was needed for Eclipse to function.