# How to regenerate .apt_generated folder

Tags: eclipse, java-ee-6

Looks like I am missing my .apt_generated and ejbModule folders in my JEE projects.

I get this exception:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Source folder '.apt_generated' in project 'ent_randomCode_impl' cannot output to distinct source folder 'ejbModule'
```

I looked in my project explorer for the folder, even changed the view customization to display *.resources'.  Can't see it.  How do I get eclipse to regenerate those folders?

If any of you has figured this out, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Wow, I see this question has still not been answered.  Looks like I have run into it again.  Guess I am back to square one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I found an answer.  Or at the very least I found steps to mitigate the problem.

1) right click on your project and go to Build Path > configure Build Path
2) Go to the source tab and remove the .apt_generate folder.
3) Clean your project and then re-add the folder to your project.

That worked for me, not sure if it will work for you, and I am not sure why it worked either.  Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error about '.apt_generated' missing in Eclipse, but other compilation errors were not shown, and the the underlying cause turned out to be  this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18075742

The solution was a combination of restarting Eclipse, reimporting projects, and doing a clean.