# Cannot build Eclipse RCP project with Tycho and Java 9

Tags: java, maven, osgi, tycho, java-9

My Eclipse RCP Maven project builds fine with Java 8, but fails with Java 9:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] Could not start bundle org.eclipse.equinox.registry
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.registry [42]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="[3.7.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="3.8.0.v20160315-1450"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.equinox.common [18]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs; resolution:="optional"
    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.core.jobs"; bundle-version="3.8.0.v20160209-0147"; version="0.0.0"
       org.eclipse.core.jobs [6]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="3.8.0.v20160315-1450"; singleton:="true"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.tryActivateBundle(DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.activateBundlesInWorkingOrder(DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.doStart(DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.start(DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.checkStarted(DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService(DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService(DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.initialize(P2DependencyResolver.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.initialize(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.activate(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler.schedule(BeanScheduler.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.manage(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBeanBinder.afterInjection(PlexusBeanBinder.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.notifyListeners(MembersInjectorImpl.java:119)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultDependencyResolverFactory.lookupDependencyResolver(DefaultDependencyResolverFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.setupProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:267)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:563)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this error? I tried to set `MAVEN_OPTS=--add-modules java.se.ee` but this didn't help.

My JDK version is `9-ea+175`.

---

## UPDATE

I upgraded `tycho` version from 0.25.0 to 1.0.0. Now the build starts fine but fails later with hundreds of errors like:

```
... Compilation failure:
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Comment: Is it a project that you can make available?

Comment: @KarlRichter Unfortunately no. This is a huge proprietary project.

Comment: Could you share your compiler configuration in pom.xml?

Comment: I also get `The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. `<build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
     <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>`

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Did you happen to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind) after the update?

Comment: @nullpointer This build error has nothing to do with Eclipse IDE. I'm running it from the command line with Maven.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Not though eclipse, but cleaning the project using maven doesn't help?

Comment: @nullpointer I think tycho just doesn't support Java 9 yet: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=514471

Answer (score 2):

This can be because of the few plugins/bundles which were not available during the Runtime/debug.  Please visit your project `"Run Configurations.."` and go to `Plug-ins` tab. Enable the below plug-ins

```
 1. org.eclipse.equinox.ds
 2. org.eclipse.team.core
 3. org.eclipse.ui.trace
 4. org.eclipse.equinox.util
 5. org.eclipse.equinox.common
```

and then you click on "`Add Required Plug-ins`" button present in the right side and click `Apply` and `Run` the application again.

Similar kind of bug has been already reported in eclipse [Eclipse Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494913). You can refer this also.