# object cannot be resolved eclipse unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse from quite long time to develop the Java web project, today in one of the class i started making some changes and unexpectedly Eclipse started behaving weird. Please have a look attached image, its giving compilation issue for some of the object which is already declared.

I tried below things

1. Compile whole project again.
2. Build the project
3. Close the project and reopen it again.

But nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java project in Eclipse: The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind)

Comment: you must check error log

Answer (score 0):

Have you try eclipse -> project -> clean