# unable to compile android code - java.lang.Object cannot be resolved error

Tags: react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am currently getting and build failed error. Tried uninstalling android studios, uninstall and reinstall java but to no avail. Appreciate any advice here. Thank you.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:greendao'.

  > Found 4 problem(s) parsing "/xxx/android/app/src/main/java/com/eatsy/printer/Printer.java". First problem:
  >   Pb(324) The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files (16777540 at line 1).

Android Studio 3.2
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5014246, built on September 18, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind) SO question?

Comment: Nope. I am currently using Android Studios. Hence its a different problem

Answer (score 2):

Please use Oracle JDK. OpenJDK has some issues with greenDAO. for me OracleJDK works perfect.
To install OracleJDK please follow the instructions in this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04).