# Denodo Custom Stored Procedure using Java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, denodo

Just like other error, already tried all solving solution but still get an error like this.

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project  my_denodo_extension
>   Unknown   Java Problem
>   The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files getClient.java  /my_denodo_extension/src/com/denodo/vdp/sp  line 1 Java Problem

All of the dependencies including JAR and JDK already provided.

Do you have a solution for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse to build the procedure, you may be affected by a bug in Eclipse. See this other Stackoverflow question: [Java project in Eclipse: The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind)