# minecraft eclipse The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I have decompiled minecraft's source code using MCP (mod coder pack) and opened it using eclipse IDE 2019-09 but There are two errors, The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project, and The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files. I have cleaned the project and decompiled again but the error is persistent. What can I do to fix this? If you need more information just ask.

Comment: a simple google search shows it is a fairly common error in eclipse relating to not able to load the JRE or Jav Runtime Environment but can have other reasons https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538512
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind

Comment: I have already tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind but it does **not** work and I can not find an answer in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538512 this page thanks for trying to help though I have searched through everything and i have not found an answer

Comment: Don't mod using MCP directly. Use Forge or Bukkit.